# Adding a row of totals to a dataframe

Tags: pandas, sum, append

I have a data frame and I am trying to figure out how to add a row to each client that sums up the hours for each client. Here is an example of my data frame:

```
                              hours
client           month

A               January       203.50
                February      227.75
                March         159.75
                April         203.25
                May           199.90

B               January        203.50
                February       227.75
                March         159.75
                April          203.25
                May            199.90

C               January       203.50
                February      227.75
                March          159.75
                April         203.25
                May           199.90
```

I would like to add a new row to each of the clients that sums up the hours. It would look like this:

```
                           hours
client           month

A               January    203.50
                February   227.75
                March      159.75
                April      203.25
                May        199.90
                Total     1000.34

B               January    203.50
                February   227.75
                March      159.75
                April      203.25
                May       199.90
                Total     1000.34

C               January   203.50
                February   227.75
                March      159.75
                April      203.25
                May       199.90
                Total     1000.34
```

I have tired writing a for loop that goes through each client, sums up the hours, then appends the new row to each client. The loop I am trying looks something like this

for hours in df:
    df.append(pd.Series(vp.sum(), name='Total'

However, this doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can using `concat`

```
pd.concat([df,df.sum(level=0).assign(month='Total').set_index('month',append=True)]).sort_index()
Out[1754]: 
                  hours
client month           
A      April     203.25
       February  227.75
       January   203.50
       March     159.75
       May       199.90
       Total     994.15
B      April     203.25
       February  227.75
       January   203.50
       March     159.75
       May       199.90
       Total     994.15
C      April     203.25
       February  227.75
       January   203.50
       March     159.75
       May       199.90
       Total     994.15
```

Comment: Do I put this inside a for loop? I wrote what you said, instead of add a row called "Total" to the end of each client, it added all the Total rows at the end of the df

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams did you see sort_index?

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams Yw~ happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You could `unstack` then add the column.

```
df.unstack().hours.assign(Total=lambda d: d.sum(1)).stack().to_frame('hours')

                  hours
client month           
A      April     203.25
       February  227.75
       January   203.50
       March     159.75
       May       199.90
       Total     994.15
B      April     203.25
       February  227.75
       January   203.50
       March     159.75
       May       199.90
       Total     994.15
C      April     203.25
       February  227.75
       January   203.50
       March     159.75
       May       199.90
       Total     994.15
```

---

A variation that preserves the original row order:

```
# get old order of months
months = pd.unique(df.index.get_level_values(1)).tolist()

# create total dataframe with to levels of index
totals = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    (client, 'Total'): {'hours': v}
    for client, v in df.hours.sum(level=0).items()
}, 'index')

# append and reindex
df.append(totals).sort_index().reindex(months + ['Total'], level=1)

                  hours
client month           
A      January   203.50
       February  227.75
       March     159.75
       April     203.25
       May       199.90
       Total     994.15
B      January   203.50
       February  227.75
       March     159.75
       April     203.25
       May       199.90
       Total     994.15
C      January   203.50
       February  227.75
       March     159.75
       April     203.25
       May       199.90
       Total     994.15
```